# Difference between & sign and no & sign in Sass?

Tags: css, sass

This might be a very simple answer but I couldn't find it anywhere. Might be I missed a very basic CSS rule somehow.

Here is my Sass code:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 20px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
        &.some-selector {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }
  h3.some-selector {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

What difference does it make if I pull the '&' sign off? It just adds a space between 'h3' and '.some-selctor'. What's the meaning of this space between parent and child? Is there any difference actually?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `&` would produce `h3.some-selector` (class is on `h3` element) and without it, it would produce `h3. some-selector` (class is on a descendant of `h3`). Sorry to be blunt but you need to learn CSS if you don't know what difference the space makes.

Comment: `foo.bar` and `foo .bar` are two very different things in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the & symbol will apply the rule "if" the current element has the accompanying class applied.

So in your example, the `&` rules (bigger font size and bottom margin) only apply IF the `h3` also has the class `.some-selector`. eg:

`<h3 class="some-selector"> My heading this is</h3>`

If you removed the `&` sign, you are now defining a rule for its children (the space you noticed). So that would work with html such as:

`<h3> My heading <span class="some-selector">this is</span></h3>`

You can read more on this here:
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 4):

The `&` shown effectively means "combine/join with this selector".

```
h3 {
  &.some-selector {
```

results in the *CSS selector* `h3.some-selector` (matches `H3` elements that *has* the `some-selector` class), while

```
h3 {
  .some-selector {
```

results in the *CSS selector* `h3 .some-selector` (matches elements with a class `some-selector` which are *descendants* of an `H3` element) and, expanding,

```
h3 {
  h3.some-selector {
```

results in the *CSS selector* `h3 h3.some-selector`.

See:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ (technical, but so much good information including precedence and CSS expression rules!)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors